# Toggle button in table header if at least one row has certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table that should show a button in the table header if one or more rows in the table body have been selected and have the class the TR class is "active" otherwise the button should be hidden.

HTML:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header
        <button type="button" class="add-all-selection">Add Selected Items</button></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Item 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="active">
      <td>Item 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The JavaScript that is not working:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
        if($('tr').hasClass(".active")){
             $(this).prev().hasClass(".add-all-selection").fadeIn(0);
        }
        else {
            $('.add-all-selection').fadeOut(0);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: are you trying this? http://jsfiddle.net/f92Lveov/

Comment: I have a separate script that adds the "active" class to a TR row if you click on it...now I need to get the code working that if any of the TR rows have that active class the button in the header would show up.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind click event to `tr` elements (or better, delegate click to parent table) and toggle active class. At the same time, on each click you need to check if the button should be hidden or visible.

Possible implementation can be:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $table = $('table').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');

        if ($table.find('tr.active').length) {
            $table.find(".add-all-selection").fadeIn();
        } else {
            $table.find(".add-all-selection").fadeOut();
        }
    });
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/n0j9g8ac/

Comment: That works great in your example, however I am using http://www.datatables.net/ for the table, and the button appears as soon as the page loads...

Comment: @zemaker, Try to use DataTables `initComplete` property to add the code above and see if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

**Html code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app2.js"></script>
<style>
td {border: 1px black solid; padding: 5px; cursor: pointer;}
 .selected{
    background-color: brown;
    color: #FFF;
}
</style>    
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Header
            <button type="button" class="add-all-selection">Add Selected Items</button></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Item 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Item 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr >
          <td>Item 3</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var cssProperties = {'color': 'green', 'background-color': 'blue'};
     $('.add-all-selection').hide();
     $("table tr").on('click', function(e){
       $(this).toggleClass('selected');
       //$(e.currentTarget).css(cssProperties);
       var value=$(this).find('td:first').html();
       //alert(value);    
       $('.add-all-selection').show();
     });
 });
```